# Cast value of type AnyObject contained in Dictionary

Tags: casting, swift

I have a Dictionary of with String keys, that contains values of different types. It is loaded from a plist file. I want to assign the values from the dictionary to a variable. For some reason I require two lines to cast the value to a concrete type. For example this code works:

```
var stockItemData: [String: AnyObject]
var typeTemp: AnyObject? = stockItemData["type"]
var type = typeTemp as String
```

While this does not work:

```
var stockItemData: [String: AnyObject]
var type = stockItemData["type"] as String
```

Here the compiler gives the error message (String, AnyObject) is not convertible to String. However obviously it is able to do the cast, as the above code that does the same thing in two lines of code works.

Can someone explain to me, why this is the case? Also is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is because String doesn't conform to AnyObject, but NSString does. When you do it in two steps swift is able to cast the unknown AnyObject to NSString and then bridge it to a swift string. There are a couple ways you can get around this.

The easiest is to make your dictionary a `[String : Any]`. Since String conforms to Any you can cast an Any as String.

```
var stockItemData: [String: Any] = ["type": "hello"]
var type = stockItemData["type"] as String
```

If you aren't able to change the type of your dictionary you can still do the two step cast in one line and remove the need for a temp variable.

```
var stockItemData: [String: AnyObject] = ["type": "hello"]
var type = stockItemData["type"] as AnyObject? as String
```